# Angular 6 ngb-modal with RxJS and BehaviorSubject not working

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-bootstrap, behaviorsubject

I am experimenting with the new A6, but something is still elusive.

**Expected:** As you click the button to see a Modal open

**Observed:** No errors, but no modal also ... simply nothing

Any suggestions what has been missing?

The code here in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/zaggi-angular-ngb-modal-with-subject)

Comment: Your `app-my-modal` component is not initialized because you didn't use it in template. Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqhz6q?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I guess Modal component needs to be declared in `entrycomponents` array, no  need to explicitly declared in any template

Comment: I guess Problem is that you have written `subscription` in modal component ts file which is not yet initialized.

Comment: Also I am not sure why you want to use `behaviourSubject` to dispatch event to open modal...you can directly do it

Comment: @yurzui, exactly, that's what was missing !

Comment: @user1608841, I updated the code, this option is now working - you may test in the provided stackblitz by commenting the modal element in app component template and app component declaration in app module AND adding the modal component to entry components in app module. 
The behaviorSubject is used to attempt possible late subscription. Actually Subject is used in the app that I am debugging and as you probably now guess - it's a wrapper so that in all places in the app where you need a modal, you can call the service vs repeating modal element on manly places in the app

Comment: @zaggi by following the steps you said ; modal popup is not opening. and adding `<app-my-modal></app-my-modal>` in the appcomponent html you are not leveraging dynamic component concept of angular. In Ideal scenario while implementing modal popup; modalComponent should be in entryComponene not AppComponent and we dont have to include  `<app-my-modal></app-my-modal>` anywhere in any HTML .

Comment: @user1608841, typo above ('not' instead of 'now'). My idea is to have one place (enough), where to put the modal tag (app component is a good candidate for this scenario) AND have it controlled via the modal service. HOWEVER, there are other possible approaches and what I meant above was that if one puts just the modal component (instead of app component in this example) in the app module's entry components - the modal wouldn't show - at least that're my observations by experimenting... correct me if I am wrong. Appreciation for taking a look into it !